# Unity: Prefab image is scaled

Tags: unity

[image]

I have a question regarding to the size of images in the prefab versus UI/Image.
When I drag prefab(SlotWheel) into the Scene editor, my images get scale larger.
The original image that composed become the prefab is on the right (UI/Image) with 100 width and 100 height.
In this case, how do I recalculate the height on each UI/Image in the prefabs - even though I multiply the height with scale y still doesn't add up with the height of the canvas?
 I have preset Canvas Scaler's reference resolution to x:1136 and y:640. And canvas render mode is set to Screen space overlay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can clearly see right there in the transform of "SlotWheel", that your SlotWheel object, has a scale of "3.901" on (x,y,z).

So all your little child objects that belong to SlotWheel, will all have a scale of :

The child's scale * parent's scale.

Just set the parent "SlotWheel" to 1, and all the children to 1, and you'll have the usual scale of the UI/Image you showed.

Comment: if this the case, is there a way for me to preset all the scale become 1? Or do I need to set it to 1 every time I add a new prefabs?

Comment: I don't think it's that much work to set a prefab's scale..